# VBA put outcomes IF statements into one cell as a listing

Tags: vba, class, if-statement, range

My question is simple I guess, but I can't figure it out.
Translation: Ja=Yes / Nee=No

So if cell A2 says "Nee" there should be a sentence in J2 if not then do nothing.
This is the same for al the other cells in each row.

I got my code running that it does the if statements. BUT it just need to be merged into one cell.

The Excel screenshot with an example of how it should be is as follows:

[image: Excel screenshot with example how it should be]

Code:

```
Sub SampleMacro()
' Get the last row
Dim startRow As Long, lastRow As Long
startRow = 2
lastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim i As Long, Wat As String
Dim j As Long, Waarom As String

Dim sClass As String
Dim tClass As String

' Go through the parameter columns
For i = startRow To lastRow
    Wat = Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value

    ' Check parameters and classify accordingly
    If Wat = "Nee" Then
        sClass = " Er wordt in de cookie policy niet uitgelegd wat cookies zijn."
    Else
        sClass = ""
    End If

For j = startRow To lastRow
    Waarom = Sheet1.Range("B" & j).Value

    If Waarom = "Nee" Then
        tClass = "  Waarom ze nuttig zijn is hier niet omschreven."
    Else
        tClass = ""
    End If

     ' Write out the class to columns
    Sheet1.Range("J" & i).Value = sClass
    Sheet1.Range("K" & j).Value = tClass

Next

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Is VBA really required? Maybe, using the builtin IF-function (see https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) is sufficient.

Comment: So if on column A says "Nee" in column J must be  "Er wordt in de cookie policy niet uitgelegd wat cookies zijn." and if on column B says "Nee" on column K must be "  Waarom ze nuttig zijn is hier niet omschreven." ? Is that it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can be simplified to this:

```
For i = startRow To lastRow
    ' Check parameters and classify accordingly
    If Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
        Sheet1.Range("J" & i).Value = " Er wordt in de cookie policy niet uitgelegd wat cookies zijn."
    End If
    ' If there's Nee in B column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
    If Sheet1.Range("B" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
        Sheet1.Range("J" & i).Value = Sheet1.Range("J" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "  Waarom ze nuttig zijn is hier niet omschreven."
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting this formula in column J, this way you avoid using macros

```
=IF(A2="Nee",IF(B2="Nee"," Er wordt in de cookie policy niet uitgelegd wat cookies zijn." &CHAR(10)& "  Waarom ze nuttig zijn is hier niet omschreven."," Er wordt in de cookie policy niet uitgelegd wat cookies zijn."),"")
```